# IsUserInRole fails true condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, openid

I’m trying to integrate OpenID into my MVC3 Razor application.  The OpenID is working but when I try and test a User’s membership in a Role the test fails.

Two Roles:

“MainUser” with one user named “User”.
“GuestUser” with one user named “Guest”.

Here’s my form in my Logon.cshtml

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])" method="post" id="openid_form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify" />
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login using OpenID</legend>
        <div class="openid_choice">
            <p>
                Please click your account provider:</p>
            <div id="openid_btns">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="openid_input_area">
            @Html.TextBox("openid_identifier")
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <p>
                OpenID is service that allows you to log-on to many different websites using a single
                indentity. Find out <a href="http://openid.net/what/">more about OpenID</a> and
                <a href="http://openid.net/get/">how to get an OpenID enabled account</a>.</p>
        </noscript>
        <div>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName))
                {
                  <div class="editor-label">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenID)
                  </div>
                  <div class="editor-field">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenID)
                  </div>
                  <p class="button">
                      @Html.ActionLink("New User ,Register", "Register", new { OpenID = Model.OpenID })
                  </p>
                }
                else
                {
                //user exist 
                  <p class="buttonGreen">

                    @Model.UserName,

                    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole("MainUser"))
                      { <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Main")">Welcome @Model.UserName, Continue... </a> }

                    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole("GuestUser"))
                      { <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Guest")">Welcome @Model.UserName, Continue... </a> }

                      <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Main")">Role test failed for @Model.UserName  </a>
                  </p>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

I run the app and successfully authenticate with OpenId and get a green block containing:
User, Role test failed for User

This shows a successful logon as “User” and that it made it to the else code block but the IsUserInRole test failed.

If I add the not operator to the first test [  @if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("MainUser"))   ] the test passes.

The question is why does “User” fail the IsUserInRole test.  I’ve triple checked that I have all my Roles and Users spelled correctly and that the Users are in the proper Roles.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using OpenId without any support from FormsAuthentication that it could be that the RoleProvider does not know how to check the roles. The `Roles.IsUserInRole` method relies upon `RoleProvider.IsUserInRole` to check whether a currently active user belongs to the requested role. The actual return value of `RoleProvider.IsUserInRole` according to MSDN documentation is:

> true if the specified user is in the specified role for the configured
>   applicationName; otherwise, false.

This **applicationName** should be set in the web.config file. If you are not using RoleProvider then that is the reason why your check keeps failing. RoleProvider is defined as following in configuration/system.web:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="YourDbConnectionString" 
             applicationName="MySampleAppName"
             name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Of course, this expects you to store your roles in aspnetdb database. However, you can implement your own RoleProvider if this one does not suit you well.

Comment: My <fileManager enabled "true"> is configured correctly and I use the IsUserInRole successfully in other parts of the application.  My authorization database has been merged into the main database.  Your first sentence may be the problem, I do not use FormsAuthentication, the OpenId form never psots back to the action but is handled via the java script.  It has become a moot issue at this point since I'm only going to have one login so I don't need to run the IsUserInRole function.  I'll mark this as the answer and comment furhter if I should look at it more in the future.  Thank you

Comment: My <fileManager enabled "true"> is configured correctly and I use the IsUserInRole successfully in other parts of the application.  My authorization database has been merged into the main database.  Your first sentence may be the problem, I do not use FormsAuthentication, the OpenId form never posts back to the action but is handled via the java script.  It has become a moot issue at this point since I'm only going to have one login so I don't need to run the IsUserInRole function.  I'll mark this as the answer and comment further if I should look at it more in the future.  Thank you